# New NestJS Axios is not returning me anything?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, nestjs

I'm currently using the @nestjs/axios lib, as instructed on the documentation, but I'm struggling to make a simple API call:

```js
 const test = this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3001/test/testificate')
```

What I get is an observable, without any value, the same goes for POST requests... I'm used to dealing with Axios, that had async methods, but right now, I can't even make my client wait for axios to finish that call

Answer (score 0):

`@nestjs/axios` returns Observable objects from [`rxjs`](https://rxjs.dev/) lib. Thus you need to learn on how to work with them.

If you want a Promise-based wrapper for `axios`, you could use this package: [`nestjs-http-promise`](https://github.com/benhason1/nestjs-http-promise), or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

in service:

```
find(): Observable<AxiosResponse<YourInterfaceData>> {
return this.httpService.get<YourInterfaceData>{url}
  }
```

in controller:

```
@Get()
find(@Res()response:Response) {    
    this.dnirucService.findOne(doc).subscribe(v => response.send(v));}
```

remember import Response from express:

```
import { Response } from 'express';
```

and import in your module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({
      timeout: 5000,
      maxRedirects: 5,
    }),
  ]
```